# How to branch from the catch block to finally - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I understand that the "finally" part of the code will always run, but I dont see it happening in my code. Please help.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + $TDEnv + ";Connection Pooling Timeout=300;User Id=" + $TDUserID + ";Password=" + $TDPswd + ";"
try{
    $connection.Open()
}
catch{
    Write-Host "An error occurred acquiring the connection to Teradata"
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    Exit 99
}

$SqlCommand = "SELECT TableName AS TDProcName FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE 1 = 1 AND TableKind = '" + $TableKind + "' AND DatabaseName = '" + $DBName + "';"
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $sqlCommand

$adapter = $factory.CreateDataAdapter()
$adapter.SelectCommand = $command

$dataset = new-object System.Data.DataSet


try{
    [void] $adapter.Fill($dataset)

    $ProcNames = $dataset.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows

    #------Build the actual BTeq script------#
    ForEach($procNm in $ProcNames){

        #--------------------- This needs to be changed to make it dynamic, based on the param passed in ---------------------#
        $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".EXPORT DATA FILE = E:\TFSObjects\BI\" + $Environment + "\Teradata\Procs\" + $procNm.Item(0).ToString() + ".sql; `r`n"
        $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".SET RECORDMODE OFF; `r`n"
        $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + "SHOW " + $ObjName +  "  " + $DBName + "." + $procNm.Item(0).ToString() + "; `r`n `r`n `r`n"
        #$bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".EXPORT RESET; `r`n `r`n `r`n"
    }

    $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".LOGOFF; `r`n `r`n `r`n"
    $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".EXIT 0;"

    Write-Host "This shouldnt show up on the screen `r`n"

    #----Materialize the script object to a file----#
    $bTeqScrObj | Out-File -FilePath $OutFile

    #------Run the actual BTeq script------#
    cat $OutFile | bteq
}
catch{
    Write-Host "An error occurred while processing the request:"
    Write-Host $_       
}   

finally{

        Write-Host "Yep, still got here!"

        if($connection.State -eq "Open"){
            $connection.Close()
        }

    }
```

But what I see is that the finally part of the code isn't showing up. 
So, I want the code to branch to finally from the first catch block. Why is it not happening?

However, if there is an error in the second try/catch block, it does go to the finally part.

P.S: I tried removing the Exit, replaced it with throw, and still the same result.

Comment: I don't think I have ever thought that there could be code execution between the `catch{}finally{}` But I don't think that's possible it's like having `if{} /* add some code*/ else{}` You'll need to put your `$SqlCommand` lines inside the catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + $TDEnv + ";Connection Pooling Timeout=300;User Id=" + $TDUserID + ";Password=" + $TDPswd + ";"
try{
    $connection.Open()
}
catch{
    Write-Host "An error occurred acquiring the connection to Teradata"
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    Exit 99
}
finally {
    CleanUpDbConnection($connection)
}

$SqlCommand = "SELECT TableName AS TDProcName FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE 1 = 1 AND TableKind = '" + $TableKind + "' AND DatabaseName = '" + $DBName + "';"
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $sqlCommand

$adapter = $factory.CreateDataAdapter()
$adapter.SelectCommand = $command

$dataset = new-object System.Data.DataSet


try{
    [void] $adapter.Fill($dataset)

    $ProcNames = $dataset.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows

    #------Build the actual BTeq script------#
    ForEach($procNm in $ProcNames){

        #--------------------- This needs to be changed to make it dynamic, based on the param passed in ---------------------#
        $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".EXPORT DATA FILE = E:\TFSObjects\BI\" + $Environment + "\Teradata\Procs\" + $procNm.Item(0).ToString() + ".sql; `r`n"
        $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".SET RECORDMODE OFF; `r`n"
        $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + "SHOW " + $ObjName +  "  " + $DBName + "." + $procNm.Item(0).ToString() + "; `r`n `r`n `r`n"
        #$bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".EXPORT RESET; `r`n `r`n `r`n"
    }

    $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".LOGOFF; `r`n `r`n `r`n"
    $bTeqScrObj = $bTeqScrObj + ".EXIT 0;"

    Write-Host "This shouldnt show up on the screen `r`n"

    #----Materialize the script object to a file----#
    $bTeqScrObj | Out-File -FilePath $OutFile

    #------Run the actual BTeq script------#
    cat $OutFile | bteq
}
catch{
    Write-Host "An error occurred while processing the request:"
    Write-Host $_       
}   

finally{

        Write-Host "Yep, still got here!"

        CleanDbConnection($connection)

    }`enter code here`


function CleanDbConnection {
      if($args[0].State -eq "Open"){
                $args[0].Close()
            }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I actually have multiple try catch blocks and the finally comes right after the last catch, let me modify my code above to give you a clearer picture.

Comment: @Number10 oh, that's much easier to understand. I see your misunderstanding of the syntax. `try{}catch{}finally{}` must match `finally` is optional so when it's omitted in the first `try{}catch{}` block it will never trigger the finally since `Exit` is being called along with no finally block for that specific `try{}catch{} `

Comment: my suggestion is to create a function that you can call for both `finally` blocks

Comment: ah! Thanks Andrei, I didn't know that you could have multiple `Finally` blocks in a script, I always thought you can have only one `finally` block per script and that gets executed regardless of which `try{} catch{}` it belonged to.

Comment: @Number10 no worries, I've edited my answer with a possible fix to keep things dry (Don't repeat yourself)